# "focus is not a function" in Vue.js even though element exists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to focus on a textarea in Vue.js, but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: _this2.$refs[ref].focus is not a function
```

This is the textarea:

```
<textarea v-model="text[key].content" :ref="text[key].text_id" class="text-textarea" @focus="makeCurrent(key)" v-on:keyup="detectVariable(key, text[key].text_id)"></textarea>
```

This is my code:

```
let ref = 'foobar';
console.log(this.$refs[ref]);
this.$refs[ref].focus();
```

The `console.log` prints out the correct textarea:

```
0: textarea.text-textarea
```

But when I try to focus I get the error mentioned above. I don't understand this behavior at all. The `ref` exists and points to the correct `textarea` (it's the only `textarea` on the page for now, to avoid confusion) but `focus` is not a function on it?

Comment: @kiner_shah Defined? I've never needed to explicitly define `$refs` in `Vue` before.

Comment: Is the text area within a v-for loop? If so, ref behaves differently and is an array of the refs within that loop. For example, if I have a `ref` of 'textArea` with 3 iterations of the loop, I have this.$refs['textArea'][0], this.$refs['textArea'][1], this.$refs['textArea'][2]. To focus the first I'd do `this.$refs['textArea'][0].focus()`

Comment: @steve16351 Yeah that's it. There's a for loop. I was blinded by the fact there's only one element in it so far.

Answer (score 8):

When a `ref` is used inside a `v-for` loop, it behaves differently, and the ref is an array of the elements/components with a given ref within the loop.

For example, if I have the following, where keys contains multiple values,

```
<div v-for="key in keys">
    <textarea ref="textAreaInput">
</div>
```

To focus the first, I'd do `this.$refs['textAreaInput'][0].focus()`